# vim-go: How to open files returned by GoFiles

Tags: vim, go

Vim-go plugin has a :GoFile function to show source files that depends on the current package. The output looks like this:

```
['/home/tretkow/tut/main.go', '/home/tretkow/tut/test.go']
```

How to open files from the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:GoFiles` only echoes the output of `go#tool#Files()`.

From the look of your snippet, it should be possible to extract a filename with something like:

```
:e <C-r>=go#tool#Files()[0]<CR>
```

or put that list in a scratch buffer:

```
:vnew<CR>
:0put=join(go#tool#files(), '\r')<CR>

/home/tretkow/tut/main.go
/home/tretkow/tut/test.go
```

and use `gf` to jump to the file under the cursor.

---

Here is a more sophisticated solution: the `:GoFile` command lets you choose what file from the `:GoFiles` command to edit via custom tab-completion.

```
" the command
command! -nargs=1 -complete=customlist,GoFilesComplete GoFile call GoFile(<f-args>)

" the completion function
function! GoFilesComplete(ArgLead, CmdLine, CursorPos)
    return filter(go#tool#Files(), 'v:val =~ a:ArgLead')
endfunction

" the :edit wrapper
function GoFile(file)
    execute "edit " . a:file
endfunction
```

Usage:

```
:GoFile <Tab>
```

Comment: The snippet starting with vnew is not working for me. Seems that go#tool#Files() gives different output when called from scratch buffer. Also join(..., '\r') gives me single line with visible \r. But :GoFile is perfect! Thank you.

Comment: Hmm... I should have noted none of that was tested.